# Strange behavior (unnamed namespace with swscanf)

Tags: c++, gcc, scanf, wstring, unnamed-namespace

I have the next experimental code. That code fail with segmentation fault on the labeled line.

If I take out the str2MxfKey function from anonymous namespace or give a some name to namespace, code will run without any problem.

That strange behavior reproduced only on the release build. Could someone explain me root cause of that problem?

Ubuntu 22.04, cmake 3.22.1, gcc 11.3.0

```
struct mxfKey
{
    uint8_t octet0;
    uint8_t octet1;
    uint8_t octet2;
    uint8_t octet3;
    uint8_t octet4;
    uint8_t octet5;
    uint8_t octet6;
    uint8_t octet7;
    uint8_t octet8;
    uint8_t octet9;
    uint8_t octet10;
    uint8_t octet11;
    uint8_t octet12;
    uint8_t octet13;
    uint8_t octet14;
    uint8_t octet15;
};

namespace {
    mxfKey str2MxfKey(const std::wstring &str) {
        mxfKey k;

        int rc = swscanf(str.c_str(),
                         L"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", // mxfkey
                         &k.octet0, &k.octet1, &k.octet2, &k.octet3,
                         &k.octet4, &k.octet5, &k.octet6, &k.octet7,
                         &k.octet8, &k.octet9, &k.octet10, &k.octet11,
                         &k.octet12, &k.octet13, &k.octet14, &k.octet15);
        if (rc != 16) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Error in str2MxfKey");
        }
        return k;
    }
}

void someExperiments() {
    std::wstring wstr = L"8c2197ad00e9476b8213b367123e506e";

    std::wcout << "Start" << std::endl;
    str2MxfKey(wstr);
    std::wcout << wstr << std::endl; // <----  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    std::wcout << "End" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    someExperiments();
    ...
}
```

Comment: the cause for a segfault is often not where the segfault happens. Also changing seemingly unrelated parts of the code having impact on what the code does is a good indication for undefined behavior.

Comment: [works without problems for me](https://godbolt.org/z/3fx534xqv) please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles You should have compiled this with -Wpedantic or something similar. VS2022 gives this warning explaining the problem:

rning C4477: 'swscanf' : format string '%02x' requires an argument of type 'unsigned int *', but variadic argument 16 has type 'uint8_t *'

Comment: @Gunther weird, can't get gcc or clang to complain about this code https://godbolt.org/z/5Td44G8Kd

Comment: Looks like clang and gcc don't crash if the with of the bytes is short enough: https://godbolt.org/z/K1fKzh3nz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swscanf format string is wrong. %02x expects an unsigned int and not uint8_t.

Try this instead:

```
    int rc = swscanf(str.c_str(),
        L"%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx", // mxfkey
        &k.octet0, &k.octet1, &k.octet2, &k.octet3,
        &k.octet4, &k.octet5, &k.octet6, &k.octet7,
        &k.octet8, &k.octet9, &k.octet10, &k.octet11,
        &k.octet12, &k.octet13, &k.octet14, &k.octet15);
```

Comment: Seems it's work, but could you please explain, what is mean "hh" in "%02hhx?

Comment: hh means "signed char*" length specifier. (https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: Thank you. I approved you answer as right. But please fix "%02x" to "%02hhx" in last item in format string.